# Rewrite entire dynamic path with Express 3 and 4

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a directory structure like so:

```
/scripts
   server.js

/docs
   node_modules
   app.css
   index.html
```

Originally I had some static routes to map files in the server.js:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(basePath, './docs/index.html'));
});
app.get('/app.css', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(basePath, './docs/app.css'));
});
```

But now I need to globally include any search path under `node_modules` as well, something like:

```
app.get('/node_modules*', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(basePath, './docs/( - complete subtree - )'));
});
```

But that obviously doesn't work. It seems like a URL rewrite is more appropriate here, but I can't figure out how to do that with `app.get` or with `app.configure` + some `express.static` magic.

How can I route an entire directory to a different physical folder, retaining the subpaths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `express.static` to static files.

```
var path = require('path');
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../docs/node_modules')));
```

Hope it helps you.